# Is there a macro to conditionally copy data to another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

At my work I have two databases with the same products. The first database contains all the products with all possible combinations (in this istance the database consists of motor exhausts, which are available in different colors and materials). The second database only contains the base product. The product ID of the combinations correspondences with the ID of the base products. The database with the base products also contains a lot of information about the products.

**Sample data combinations**

```
- Product ID - Reference number
1.12012        E3A02ET7
2.12012        E3A02EN7
3.12013        E3A02ES6
4.12014        E9A03ES
5.12014        E9A03EN
```

**Sample data base**

```
- Product ID - Name     -     Price - Reference number
1.12012        Gilera Fuoco   €363    E3A02ET
2.12013        Gilera Nexus   €363    E3A02ES
3.12014        Gilera Runner  €363    E9A03EN
```

**Prefered output**

```
 - Product ID - Name     -     Price - Reference number
1. 12012        Gilera Fuoco   €363    E3A02ET7
2. 12012        Gilera Fuoco   €363    E3A02EN7
3. 12013        Gilera Nexus   €363    E3A02ES6
4. 12014        Gilera Runner  €363    E9A03ES
5. 12014        Gilera Runner  €363    E9A03EN
```

Since I want to upload every product to my webshop, I need to format the combinations database in the same way as the base product database, with all the useful information. The way I want to do this, is to use a macro that only copies the combinations product reference number, with the entire base product row, if the combinations product's ID matches the base product's ID. Since a lot of combinations products match the same base product's ID, the macro needs to copy the data multiple times. Also, the combinations database has information about the exhaust's material and color in another colon (I exluded it to make my sample database less messy.). If it's possible, I want to add this information to the product name.

This is what I have now:

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Condition As Worksheet


    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad2")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad3")
    Set Condition = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")

    j = 1    
      For Each d In Condition.Range("A1:A86")
        For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A893")
            If d = c Then
                Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
      Next d
End Sub
```

Much obliged,

B. van Starkenburg

Comment: Please show us your code and what have you tried until now.

Comment: @Berend - really a well asked question, you simply miss the point that this is not a code-for-me-site and etc... Thus, show what you have tried until now.

Comment: @Vityata, Hmm, my fault. I uploaded this question before reading the guidelines.

Comment: @Vityata - I added the macro that I use now. The problem is that the reference ID stays the same as the base product reference ID. However, I want it to copy the combinations product reference ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Just rename the three worksheets to `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim a               As Long '- do not name like this

    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim rngCell2        As Range

    Dim rngSource       As Range

    With Worksheets("B")
        Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 1))
    End With

    Worksheets("C").Cells.Clear

    With Worksheets("A")

    For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 1))
        For Each rngCell2 In rngSource
            If rngCell2 = rngCell Then
                a = a + 1
                Worksheets("C").Rows(a).Value = Worksheets("B").Rows(rngCell2.Row).Value
                Worksheets("C").Cells(a, 4) = rngCell.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        Next rngCell2
    Next rngCell

    End With

End Sub
```

This is the result:

[image]

To make the code further workable, make sure that you make the ranges and the arrays with variables.

Comment: @BerendStarkenburg - welcome. A few ideas for the next time you ask - make sure to remove all unnecessary info from your question and to summarize it to input, output and business logic. Otherwise, it gets too large. + always include what have you tried so far + code.